# Angular Material Table how to invert an icon in only one row?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-table with 3 icons in each row. One of the icons is an arrow that opens up an expandable row when pressed. I want to invert the icon when it's pressed but only the specific one being pressed, not all arrows in all rows.

I'm using ngClass on a boolean to invert the arrow

HTML:

```html
<div class="icon open" (click)="expand(element)" [ngClass]="isopened ? 'inverted':</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.inverted {
transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

Ts:

```js
  expand(element: any) {
    ...

    this.isopened = !this.isopened;
  }
```

How can I only toggle the specific clicked icon?

Comment: How do you build your rows' content - from some object or something else? Is the table built dynamically? You'd need some way to differentiate between the rows or buttons, so it would be useful if you share more html or ts.

Comment: @MishaMashina The table is built by using element to loop through an array. It is exactly like this: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src/app/table-basic-example.ts

So each row has 'element' to differentiate between rows. But the icons are just div's inside of the rows.

Comment: I cannot open your link. Is it like this https://stackblitz.com/angular/dlxbkjqaoba?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts?

Comment: @MishaMashina yes that's the one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, go with something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vg4wcx?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

1. Add another property to the element's object (I've added 'isopened') as boolean (set to false initially).
2. Change the ngClass to check `element.isopened` instead of just `isopened`, because you want to check only that specific element's status.
3. Finally, in your method handling expanding of the icon, use `element` instead of `this`, since you're checking/setting the proprty of the value you've passed to the method, and the value is element itself.

Didn't use your div component details, because I'm not sure how you fit it into the table structure, but this should give you a right idea how to go about it.